# Group by and drop duplicates in pandas dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe as below. I want to group by based on all the three columns and retain the group with the max of Col1.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1':['A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B'], 'col2':['1', '1', '1', '1', '2', '3'], 'col3':['5', '5', '2', '2', '2', '3']})
df


  col1 col2 col3
0   A   1    5
1   A   1    5
2   A   1    2
3   A   1    2
4   B   2    2
5   B   3    3
```

My expected output

```
  col1 col2 col3
0   A   1    5
1   A   1    5
4   B   2    2
5   B   3    3
```

I tried below code, but it return me the last row of each group, instead I want to sort by col3 and keep the group with max col3

```
df.drop_duplicates(keep='last', subset=['col1','col2','col3'])


  col1  col2 col3
1   A   1     5
3   A   1     2
4   B   2     2
5   B   3     3
```

For Example: Here I want to drop 1st group because 2 < 5, so I want to keep the group with col3 as 5

```
df.sort_values(by=['col1', 'col2', 'col3'], ascending=False)
a_group = df.groupby(['col1', 'col2', 'col3'])
for name, group in a_group:
  group = group.reset_index(drop=True)
  print(group)

  col1 col2 col3
0    A    1    2
1    A    1    2
  col1 col2 col3
0    A    1    5
1    A    1    5
  col1 col2 col3
0    B    2    2
  col1 col2 col3
0    B    3    3
```

Comment: your expected output has duplicate did you mean 1 2 on second row?

Comment: My expected output is what I want, I want to keep the group which has the max of col3.

Comment: Do you wish to retain the index? Or you don't mind ending up with a new index?

Comment: Don't care about the index

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So we can do

```
out = df[df.col3==df.groupby(['col1','col2'])['col3'].transform('max')]
  col1 col2 col3
0    A    1    5
1    A    1    5
4    B    2    2
5    B    3    3
```

Answer (score 4):

You cant group on all columns since the col you wish to retain max for has different values. Instead dont include that column in the group and consider others:

```
col_to_max = 'col3'
i = df.columns ^ [col_to_max]
out = df[df[col_to_max] == df.groupby(list(i))[col_to_max].transform('max')]
```

---

```
print(out)

  col1 col2 col3
0    A    1    5
1    A    1    5
4    B    2    2
5    B    3    3
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can use `groupby` with `nlargest(2)`. Also make sure that your 'col3' is a numerical one.

```
>>> df['col3'] = df['col3'].astype(int)
>>> df.groupby(['col1','col2'])['col3'].nlargest(2).reset_index().drop('level_2',axis=1)

  col1 col2  col3
0    A    1     5
1    A    1     5
2    B    2     2
3    B    3     3
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get `index` which doesn't has `col3` max value and duplicated index and drop the intersection

```
ind = df.assign(max = df.groupby("col1")["col3"].transform("max")).query("max != col3").index
ind2 = df[df.duplicated(keep=False)].index

df.drop(set(ind).intersection(ind2))

  col1 col2 col3
0    A    1    5
1    A    1    5
4    B    2    2
5    B    3    3
```